# Convert string column to array - Error occurs

Tags: jupyter-notebook, data-science

I have a problem. I hope, someone can solve it.
I have a df of

| Nr. | Unit |
| --- | --- |
| 1393094 | Pieces |
| 2483u9u | Pair |

I need the "Unit" column to be converted into an array:

| Nr. | Unit |
| --- | --- |
| 1393094 | [Pieces] |
| 2483u9u | [Pair] |

dtypes are:
Nr.    object
Unit    object

This Error occurs whatever I try:
List indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not really obvious. You've said "I need the "Unit" column to be converted into an array:" but in your given example there is also Nr column.

Comment: I don´t want to touch the "Nr" column, just the "Unit" column.

Comment: If you want to get these strs in a list for each row you can do the following: DF["Unit"]=DF["Unit"].apply(lambda x: list(x)).

Comment: Thank you=) , that works but it returns  [P,i,e,c,e,s]

Comment: oh sorry instead of list(x) use [x], in the lambda function.

Comment: Yes, thank youuuu so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to have a better understanding about row operations you can search the pandas apply method for further research.